# Performance regression for big integer computation

Tags: performance-tuning, big-numbers, backslide

**Backslide introduced in 12.0, persisting through 13.1.**

---

Recently I noticed that the big integer calculation of the new version is much slower than the old version, can you reproduce, is there a way to speed up in the new version?

```
#^2 (#^2 + 1) &@Range[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

---

A short history of performance changes throughout Mathematica versions on Linux:

Linux 8.0.4:

```
In[]:= #^2 (#^2 + 1) &@Range[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming                          

Out[]= {0.730327, Null}
```

Linux 9.0.1 and 10.0.2 get faster:

```
In[]:= #^2 (#^2 + 1) &@Range[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming                          

Out[]= {0.256588, Null}
```

Linux 10.1 gets faster:

```
In[]:= #^2 (#^2 + 1) &@Range[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming                          
                                                                                
Out[]= {0.138035, Null}
```

11.3 gets very slightly faster:

```
In[]:= #^2 (#^2 + 1) &@Range[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming                          

Out[]= {0.110871, Null}
```

12.0 gets much slower:

```
In[]:= #^2 (#^2 + 1) &@Range[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming                          
                                                                                
Out[]= {2.00058, Null}
```

12.1 gets even slower:

```
In[]:= #^2 (#^2 + 1) &@Range[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming                          
                                                                                
Out[]= {2.54884, Null}
```

This performance doesn't change up to 13.0.

Comment: I think the problem might be that the computation cannot be done with machine integers and that auto-compilation therefore fails. Or something like that. It seems like V9.0 handled that more efficiently. I think using FunctionCompile to create a function that takes `"UnsignedInteger128"` argument would be your best bet.

Comment: I think it's worth reporting. Have you reported this to WRI?

Comment: @xzczd Already reported.

Comment: Reporting as a bug. If you provide the tracking number from Tech Support I can get that info linked into the report.

Comment: Is it even slower in 13.2? It is 5.33173 here.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best you can do, is to compile a function for BigInts with `FunctionCompile`. The compilation is slow, but the execution is fast:

```
fun = FunctionCompile[
  Function[Typed[arg, "ListVector"["Integer128"]], 
   Map[#^2 (#^2 + 1) &, arg]]  
];

fun @ Range[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.208568, Null}

Comment: That is slower than 0.110871 of 11.3.